# Flutter firebase messaging doesn't get notifications from firebase functions

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase functions:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.chatNotifications = functions.firestore.document("chat/{docId}").onCreate(
    (snapshot, context) => {
        admin.messaging().sendToTopic(
            "chat", 
            {
                notification: {title: "New message", body: "A new message has been sent"}, 
                data: {click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"},
            }
        );

    }

);
```

Flutter:

```
Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async{
    print(message.notification!.body.toString());
}

void main{
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic("chat");
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
}
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
firebase_core: ^2.1.1
firebase_auth: ^4.1.0
cloud_firestore: ^4.0.3
firebase_messaging: ^14.0.4
flutter_local_notifications: ^12.0.3
```

It works when I send a notification from the firebase console.
I don't get anything from firebase functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [Google cloud console api library](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library).

Select your project at the top left of your screen.

Search for "cloud messaging".

Enable cloud messaging, firebase cloud messaging api and fcm registration api.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For background triggers which in this case is `onCreate` trigger, You have to return a promise to tell function your work is completed, or function will close unexpectedly.

So return `sendToTopic()` which is a promise.

```
   return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(
            "chat", 
            {
                notification: {title: "New message", body: "A new message has been sent"}, 
                data: {click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"},
            }
        );
```